# Azure function ServiceBusTrigger connection string value not in application settings

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

Before I deploy a function app and functions through PowerShell > ARM template I dynamically get a service bus connection string and update the value in the connection binding in the function.json file. Then I deploy the function app and function.

Deployment works, but the function app returns an error message:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'Endpoint=sb://sbname.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;[Hidden Credential]' is missing or empty.

The question is: Do we really have to create an application setting on the function app with this connection string in it? Is there no other option than using the app setting?

It feels like storing the connection string in another location than on the service bus would just create another vulnerability.
I am aware that I could define `"connection": "RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS"` in the function.json file and then create an app setting with that same name, but that's not the way forward I want to go.

Comment: You can store it in key vault if all you want is more control over who has access to plaintext connection string.

Comment: @TanveerBadar What do I store in the 'connection' parameter then? The key vault secret name?

Comment: Yes, but that follows a very specific format. I suggest you [read up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app) on integrating key vault into client applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please check if my findings help to**:

- Instead of storing the Service Bus Connection String directly, you can utilize the **Azure Key Vault Service** or **Azure App Configuration Service**.

---

1. You can store the confidential values like Connection Strings, Key-value pairs, Client Secrets, Certificate Passwords, etc. in **Azure Key Vault**.

Assume you have stored the ServiceBus connection string in the Key Vault. That you want to retrieve in the Function App through Application Settings but here in the app setting you can define as:

```
"connection": @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS/)
```

This KeyVault URI cannot be accessed by any other user until they are assigned with ***System*** or ***User Assigned Managed Identity*** Permission.

2. **Azure App Configuration** is a central place where you can manage application settings and secure their accesses in one place. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71938024/16630138) for more information.

Comment: I'm looking into working with the key vault, but the above code is not valid json that I can insert in the 'function.json' file of the function. VS Code returns "value expected json". I'm also not sure my understanding is correct as you still mention Application Settings.. Maybe the app setting needs to have this @Microsoft.KeyVault value, but then what is defined in the json of the function?

Comment: This code not to be written in the `function.json` file, it has to be written in the local.settings.josn file if running locally and in Configuration > Application settings if running the Azure Functions in the cloud.

Comment: Ok, so for general understanding, there is no way to skip 'app setting'. You either store the connection string directly in the app setting, or you do it in the key vault, which makes it more secure, but you'd still need the app setting to reference the key vault.